# How to eager load? Or is it a nested Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been using Laravel for some time, and Laravels eager loading is really nice. But now i want to do it in another, much smaller project where I´m not using Laravel, with and "ordinary" query.

Currenlty I'm doing two (2) queries
`SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id = :id;` and `SELECT * FROM choices WHERE question_id = :id;`

So I would like my output from this:

```
{
  "question": {
    "id": "12",
    "content": "Question content",
    "image_url": "156ebc3206212c_qijpmnklohgfe.jpeg",
    "lastmodified": "2016-03-18 09:58:08",
  },
  "answers": [
    {
      "id": "45",
      "content": "Ja",
      "question_id": "12"
    },
    {
      "id": "46",
      "content": "nej",
      "question_id": "12"
    }
  ]
}
```

To this (my expected result):

```
{
  "question": {
    "id": "12",
    "content": "Question content",
    "image_url": "156ebc3206212c_qijpmnklohgfe.jpeg",
    "lastmodified": "2016-03-18 09:58:08",
    "answers": [
    {
      "id": "45",
      "content": "Ja",
      "question_id": "12"
    },
    {
      "id": "46",
      "content": "nej",
      "question_id": "12"
    }
  ]
}}
```

The answer column is now nested inside `questions`. The relationship between `answer` table and `question` table is the `question_id` column and `id` column.

Question table

```
+----+------------------+-----------------------------------+---------------------+
| id |     content      |             image_url             |    lastmodified     |
+----+------------------+-----------------------------------+---------------------+
| 12 | Question content | 156ebc3206212c_qijpmnklohgfe.jpeg | 2016-03-18 09:58:08 |
+----+------------------+-----------------------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer table

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | content | question_id |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 45 | ja      |          12 |
| 46 | nej     |          12 |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

## How do i nest the answers table inside the question?

Laravel call it eager loading, i don't know if it is a join query. Here is a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac9d18)

Comment: You can use a `JOIN` and then a loop to generate that output.

Comment: Okey how exactly would i do this?